# Guest Session - Data lost

Tags: libreoffice, session

I installed Ubuntu 12.04LT sometime ago in my pc. I also enabled Guest session option. My sister was using the Libre Office writer in the guest session, wrote a document and saved it. After restarting the laptop, she found that the document was not there. Even the history of firefox was cleared.

Everything works fine with administrator account.

Is it so that nothing is saved in guest session? If yes, How can I recover the files? Its pretty important!

Answer (score 2):

No, documents and data are deleted on reboot. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopTeam/Specs/Intrepid/GuestAccount

> **Documents and Data are deleted on reboot**

furthermore , by design, the guest session uses a tmpfs as home directory, and AppArmor rules completely hide /home, and **give read-only access** to /boot, /etc, /lib*, /opt, /root, /sbin, /srv, /usr, /var.

tempfs is in RAM, so with reboot data is lost, no chance of recovery, no data is written to the hard drive.

Sorry you lost data, the only thing you can do is back up your data in the future as data loss happens from time to time for any number of reasons from power loss to bugs to hardware problems and thus you need to back up your valuable data.

Answer (score 0):

No solution for the data already lost. But next time, if anyone uses a guest session and has to save something, advise them to send it over web mail (gmail & such) or upload it to a file hosting service (Google Drive, Dropbox, & the like). That will keep the data in a non-volatile accessible place.

Comment: Well, there are two options that don't require a net connection: 1. Use some external device such as a USB stick, and 2. Save it in /var/guest-data (needs to be created by an admin first) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession#Startup_dialog